# PyInstaller created GTK3 executable: gi/_gi-cpython-38.dll could not be extracted

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, gtk3

I tried to create GTK executable using PyInstaller on MSYS2 and it builds without any errors.
The command I used to create executable:
`pyinstaller --onedir --onefile --name="MyStandalone" --windowed "app.py"`

At the and I got:
`14955 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.`

When I try to run created file, I get the error below:

```
Fatal error detected

gi/_gi-cpython-38.dll could not be extracted
fopen: No such file or directory
```

How to avoid that error? Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I tried using `--noupx` option (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3600) without success. Have you found a solution on your side?

Comment: @etiennecrb Unfortunately, I didn't find anything. I rewrote the app in Java to keep it cross-platform and now it works fine.